# How to query through a DBRef in MongoDB/pymongo?

Tags: reference, mongodb, pymongo, dbref

Is it possible to query *through* a DBRef using a single find spec?

**user collection**

```
{
    'age': 30
}
```

**post collection**

```
{
    'user': DBRef('user', ...)
}
```

Is it possible to query for all post who's users are 30 in a single find step?  If not, would it be wise to create a javascript function to handle the multi-stage operation or will that cause blocking problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's not possible to do that. i would recommend either:

a) changing your data model so that all of the data is in a single document (might not be possible depending on your case).

b) querying for users who are 30 first, and then doing a second query to get posts where user is $in that list. i would do this client side rather than using server-side JS or anything like that.

Comment: A single document isn't possible at this point and I'm already going with option B.  Thanks.

Comment: I just had this problem too, and I think map/reduce may be an option too. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

Comment: how to compose the $in query? could you please come up with an example?

Comment: @green I've added an example in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

I use a Python driver, so forgive my not-so-mongodb syntax:

```
users = list(db.Users.find({'Age':30}))
posts = list(db.Posts.find({'User':{'$in':users}}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Install python **bson** package. and try as example.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.dbref import DBRef

client = MongoClient('ip', 27017)

client.the_database.authenticate('user', 'password', source='db_name')
db = client['db_name']
user = db['user']
user_id = user.find_one({'email': 'xxxxx@gmail.com'}).get('_id')

client_user_relation = db['client_user_relation']
print(client_user_relation.find_one())
print(user_id)
print(DBRef(collection = "user", id = user_id))
print(client_user_relation.find_one({'user': DBRef(collection = "user", id = user_id)}))
```